# i18n in react-alert-template-basic

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, react-intl

In my application I am using react-alert-template-basic to show alerts. In the API I write the texts directly, like:
`this.props.alert.error('<some text>');`

Now, I want to i18n the text. After a quick search, I found that `react-intl` is one of the popular choices for that. In the docs I found that the internationalization if performed when rendering, like this:

```
  <FormattedMessage
                id="welcome"
                defaultMessage={`Hello {name}, you have {unreadCount, number} {unreadCount, plural,
                  one {message}
                  other {messages}
                }`}
                values={{name: <b>{name}</b>, unreadCount}}
            />
```

I don't know how to use `react-intl` with `react-alert-basic-template`. The latter needs the string directly, not the component `FormattedMessage`.

Does anyone know how to doi it? If not, any other alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `<FormattedMessage>` component, use [`formatMessage`](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/API#formatmessage) function. You're going to need `injectIntl` HOC as well:

```
import React from 'react';
import {injectIntl, FormattedRelative} from 'react-intl';

const Component = ({intl}) => {
  this.props.alert.error(intl.formatMessage(...))

  // your component ...
}


export default injectIntl(Component);
```

---

Also, you might consider [lingui](https://github.com/lingui/js-lingui) i18n library if you're at the beginning of your project (I'm the author). It's successor to react-intl and very similar in usage. There's a [react tutorial](https://lingui.js.org/tutorials/react.html) and this example would look like this:

```
import React from "react"
import { withI18n } from "@lingui/react"

const Component = ({ i18n }) => {
  this.props.alert.error(i18n.t`some text`)

  // your component ...
}

export default withI18n(Component)
```

Comment: I am trying to follow the instructions and I get the next error when executing ``lingui init``: ``ingui-init(1) does not exist, try --help``. Do you know what is happening?

Comment: Apart from that, if I have created the message.json manually: `` {
    "Username": "my username"
}
`` but what I got after compiling is ``module.exports={languageData:{"plurals":function(n,ord){if(ord)return"other";return n==1?"one":"other"}},mes
sages:{"Username":"Username"}};
`` Note how "my username" does not appear in the generated file. What's wrong?

Comment: Do you have the latest version installed (2.4.1)? If so, could you please create an issue? https://github.com/lingui/js-lingui/issues/new/choose I tried both (init, compile) and they work as expected. I might need more info.